# How to properly stack three symbols (e.g. symbols or text above and below convergence arrows or tildes)?

Tags: stacking-symbols, substack

I would like to define a command with three arguments which stacks three symbols or text on top of each other.
The `\tmb` command below does that but creates a bit too much vertical space between the middle and the bottom
symbol. The commands `\trialone` and `\trialtwo` try to fix that with `\raisebox` but fail (see below).
Then there is a contender based on `\mystack`, but if the middle symbol is a `\to`, then it is not vertically
aligned with the division bar of a fraction right next to it, for example. Also, there is too little space
around the three stacked symbols (to the left and right); see also below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\tmb}[3]{\underset{{\scriptscriptstyle #3}}{\overset{{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}{#2}}}% *t*op, *m*iddle, *b*ottom command
\newcommand{\trialone}[3]{\underset{{\scriptscriptstyle\raisebox{2mm}{#3}}}{\overset{{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\trialtwo}[3]{\underset{{\raisebox{2mm}{\tiny #3}}}{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle #1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\mystack}[3]{\substack{#1\\{\textstyle #2}\\[-0.3mm]#3}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item LHS $\tmb{\text{approx.}}{\to}{\text{$n$ large}}$ RHS. Here you see too much vertical space for what's below the arrow.
\item LHS $\tmb{\text{approx.}}{\sim}{\text{$n$ large}}$ RHS. Here you also see too much vertical space for what's below the tilde.
\item LHS $\trialone{\text{approx.}}{\sim}{\text{$n$ large}}$ RHS. Font size not respected.
\item LHS $\trialtwo{\text{approx.}}{\sim}{\text{$n$ large}}$ RHS. Fails if the
  command contains scriptscriptstyle instead of tiny. Still, the raisebox
  command does not seem to work.
\item LHS $\mystack{\text{approx.}}{\sim}{\text{$n$ large}}$ RHS. Looks okay, but the tilde and other middle symbols are not vertically aligned correctly, see
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{A}{B} \mystack{\text{approx.}}{\to}{\text{$n$ large}} \frac{C}{D} \quad\text{versus}\quad \frac{A}{B}\tmb{\text{approx.}}{\to}{\text{$n$ large}} \frac{C}{D}.
  \end{align*}
  We see that the arrow on the left is vertically not aligned with the division bars of the two fractions. Also, there is not sufficient space around the command. None of these problems appears on the right (there is only too much vertical space between the arrow and the ``$n$ large''.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But do you want `\sim` or `\to`?

Comment: With `\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{$\sim$}` you'll see the reason for the larger space below the tilde. However, a solution which works with the tilde might not work as well with other symbols.

Comment: @egreg: Ideally, I wanted to keep the symbols an argument (so changing), but `\sim` and `\to` are probably used in most cases (I used `\tmb` for long time and only realized that the spacing is off when combining it with `\sim`). @campa: interesting, so it's more a problem of the symbol `\sim` then... Ah, I didn't try to adjust that vertically, maybe that's easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficult part is to keep the baseline pertaining to the middle symbol. This can be accomplished by typesetting a `\vbox` for the upper part, where the bottom is a `\vtop`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tmb}[3]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip\m@th
      \ialign{%
        \hfil##\hfil\cr
        $\scriptscriptstyle#1\mathstrut$\cr
        \noalign{\vspace{0.3ex}}
        \vtop{%
          \ialign{%
            \hfil##\hfil\cr
            $#2$\cr
            $\scriptscriptstyle#3\mathstrut$\cr
          }%
        }\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{X}{2}
\tmb{\text{approx.}}{\to}{n\text{ large}}
\frac{X}{2}
\tmb{\text{approx.}}{\sim}{n\text{ large}}
\frac{X}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. If one wants to adjust the vertical space between "approx." and the arrow/tilde, one can change the `\vspace{}`. How can one adjust the space between the arrow/tilde and the "n large"? Ah, got it, one can add a `\vspace{}` right after the `$2#$` part, I believe.

Comment: @MariusHofert Like at the top, `\noalign{\vspace{...}}` (fill in the value) after `\cr`.

Comment: Great, many thanks. I could also use `[4]` to create an optional argument that adds the same amount of `\vspace` above and below the middle symbol, so one can adjust it manually if required :-)